# Working on CodePen and doesn't work locally?

Tags: javascript, codepen

Here is a working CodePen which doesn't work when I export the whole code to JS HTML and CSS files locally...

https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/mYxLpR

What I'm missing and how to make it work?

Here on snippent, the code works too...!!!

I'm confused please help...

.......................................................

```js
/* See LICENSE file for terms of use */

/*
 * Text diff implementation.
 *
 * This library supports the following APIS:
 * JsDiff.diffChars: Character by character diff
 * JsDiff.diffWords: Word (as defined by \b regex) diff which ignores whitespace
 * JsDiff.diffLines: Line based diff
 *
 * JsDiff.diffCss: Diff targeted at CSS content
 *
 * These methods are based on the implementation proposed in
 * "An O(ND) Difference Algorithm and its Variations" (Myers, 1986).
 * http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.4.6927
 */
var JsDiff = (function () {
    /*jshint maxparams: 5*/
    function clonePath(path) {
        return {
            newPos: path.newPos,
            components: path.components.slice(0)
        };
    }

    function removeEmpty(array) {
        var ret = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i]) {
                ret.push(array[i]);
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    function escapeHTML(s) {
        var n = s;
        n = n.replace(/&/g, '&amp;');
        n = n.replace(/</g, '&lt;');
        n = n.replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
        n = n.replace(/"/g, '&quot;');

        return n;
    }

    var Diff = function (ignoreWhitespace) {
        this.ignoreWhitespace = ignoreWhitespace;
    };
    Diff.prototype = {
        diff: function (oldString, newString) {
            // Handle the identity case (this is due to unrolling editLength == 0
            if (newString === oldString) {
                return [{
                    value: newString
                }];
            }
            if (!newString) {
                return [{
                    value: oldString,
                    removed: true
                }];
            }
            if (!oldString) {
                return [{
                    value: newString,
                    added: true
                }];
            }

            newString = this.tokenize(newString);
            oldString = this.tokenize(oldString);

            var newLen = newString.length,
                oldLen = oldString.length;
            var maxEditLength = newLen + oldLen;
            var bestPath = [{
                newPos: -1,
                components: []
            }];

            // Seed editLength = 0
            var oldPos = this.extractCommon(bestPath[0], newString, oldString, 0);
            if (bestPath[0].newPos + 1 >= newLen && oldPos + 1 >= oldLen) {
                return bestPath[0].components;
            }

            for (var editLength = 1; editLength <= maxEditLength; editLength++) {
                for (var diagonalPath = -1 * editLength; diagonalPath <= editLength; diagonalPath += 2) {
                    var basePath;
                    var addPath = bestPath[diagonalPath - 1],
                        removePath = bestPath[diagonalPath + 1];
                    oldPos = (removePath ? removePath.newPos : 0) - diagonalPath;
                    if (addPath) {
                        // No one else is going to attempt to use this value, clear it
                        bestPath[diagonalPath - 1] = undefined;
                    }

                    var canAdd = addPath && addPath.newPos + 1 < newLen;
                    var canRemove = removePath && 0 <= oldPos && oldPos < oldLen;
                    if (!canAdd && !canRemove) {
                        bestPath[diagonalPath] = undefined;
                        continue;
                    }

                    // Select the diagonal that we want to branch from. We select the prior
                    // path whose position in the new string is the farthest from the origin
                    // and does not pass the bounds of the diff graph
                    if (!canAdd || (canRemove && addPath.newPos < removePath.newPos)) {
                        basePath = clonePath(removePath);
                        this.pushComponent(basePath.components, oldString[oldPos], undefined, true);
                    } else {
                        basePath = clonePath(addPath);
                        basePath.newPos++;
                        this.pushComponent(basePath.components, newString[basePath.newPos], true, undefined);
                    }

                    var oldPos = this.extractCommon(basePath, newString, oldString, diagonalPath);

                    if (basePath.newPos + 1 >= newLen && oldPos + 1 >= oldLen) {
                        return basePath.components;
                    } else {
                        bestPath[diagonalPath] = basePath;
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        pushComponent: function (components, value, added, removed) {
            var last = components[components.length - 1];
            if (last && last.added === added && last.removed === removed) {
                // We need to clone here as the component clone operation is just
                // as shallow array clone
                components[components.length - 1] = {
                    value: this.join(last.value, value),
                    added: added,
                    removed: removed
                };
            } else {
                components.push({
                    value: value,
                    added: added,
                    removed: removed
                });
            }
        },
        extractCommon: function (basePath, newString, oldString, diagonalPath) {
            var newLen = newString.length,
                oldLen = oldString.length,
                newPos = basePath.newPos,
                oldPos = newPos - diagonalPath;
            while (newPos + 1 < newLen && oldPos + 1 < oldLen && this.equals(newString[newPos + 1], oldString[oldPos + 1])) {
                newPos++;
                oldPos++;

                this.pushComponent(basePath.components, newString[newPos], undefined, undefined);
            }
            basePath.newPos = newPos;
            return oldPos;
        },

        equals: function (left, right) {
            var reWhitespace = /\S/;
            if (this.ignoreWhitespace && !reWhitespace.test(left) && !reWhitespace.test(right)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return left === right;
            }
        },
        join: function (left, right) {
            return left + right;
        },
        tokenize: function (value) {
            return value;
        }
    };

    var CharDiff = new Diff();

    var WordDiff = new Diff(true);
    WordDiff.tokenize = function (value) {
        return removeEmpty(value.split(/(\s+|\b)/));
    };

    var CssDiff = new Diff(true);
    CssDiff.tokenize = function (value) {
        return removeEmpty(value.split(/([{}:;,]|\s+)/));
    };

    var LineDiff = new Diff();
    LineDiff.tokenize = function (value) {
        return value.split(/^/m);
    };

    return {
        Diff: Diff,

        diffChars: function (oldStr, newStr) {
            return CharDiff.diff(oldStr, newStr);
        },
        diffWords: function (oldStr, newStr) {
            return WordDiff.diff(oldStr, newStr);
        },
        diffLines: function (oldStr, newStr) {
            return LineDiff.diff(oldStr, newStr);
        },

        diffCss: function (oldStr, newStr) {
            return CssDiff.diff(oldStr, newStr);
        },

        createPatch: function (fileName, oldStr, newStr, oldHeader, newHeader) {
            var ret = [];

            ret.push('Index: ' + fileName);
            ret.push('===================================================================');
            ret.push('--- ' + fileName + (typeof oldHeader === 'undefined' ? '' : '\t' + oldHeader));
            ret.push('+++ ' + fileName + (typeof newHeader === 'undefined' ? '' : '\t' + newHeader));

            var diff = LineDiff.diff(oldStr, newStr);
            if (!diff[diff.length - 1].value) {
                diff.pop(); // Remove trailing newline add
            }
            diff.push({
                value: '',
                lines: []
            }); // Append an empty value to make cleanup easier

            function contextLines(lines) {
                return lines.map(function (entry) {
                    return ' ' + entry;
                });
            }

            function eofNL(curRange, i, current) {
                var last = diff[diff.length - 2],
                    isLast = i === diff.length - 2,
                    isLastOfType = i === diff.length - 3 && (current.added !== last.added || current.removed !== last.removed);

                // Figure out if this is the last line for the given file and missing NL
                if (!/\n$/.test(current.value) && (isLast || isLastOfType)) {
                    curRange.push('\\ No newline at end of file');
                }
            }

            var oldRangeStart = 0,
                newRangeStart = 0,
                curRange = [],
                oldLine = 1,
                newLine = 1;
            for (var i = 0; i < diff.length; i++) {
                var current = diff[i],
                    lines = current.lines || current.value.replace(/\n$/, '').split('\n');
                current.lines = lines;

                if (current.added || current.removed) {
                    if (!oldRangeStart) {
                        var prev = diff[i - 1];
                        oldRangeStart = oldLine;
                        newRangeStart = newLine;

                        if (prev) {
                            curRange = contextLines(prev.lines.slice(-4));
                            oldRangeStart -= curRange.length;
                            newRangeStart -= curRange.length;
                        }
                    }
                    curRange.push.apply(curRange, lines.map(function (entry) {
                        return (current.added ? '+' : '-') + entry;
                    }));
                    eofNL(curRange, i, current);

                    if (current.added) {
                        newLine += lines.length;
                    } else {
                        oldLine += lines.length;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (oldRangeStart) {
                        // Close out any changes that have been output (or join overlapping)
                        if (lines.length <= 8 && i < diff.length - 2) {
                            // Overlapping
                            curRange.push.apply(curRange, contextLines(lines));
                        } else {
                            // end the range and output
                            var contextSize = Math.min(lines.length, 4);
                            ret.push(
                                '@@ -' + oldRangeStart + ',' + (oldLine - oldRangeStart + contextSize) + ' +' + newRangeStart + ',' + (newLine - newRangeStart + contextSize) + ' @@');
                            ret.push.apply(ret, curRange);
                            ret.push.apply(ret, contextLines(lines.slice(0, contextSize)));
                            if (lines.length <= 4) {
                                eofNL(ret, i, current);
                            }

                            oldRangeStart = 0;
                            newRangeStart = 0;
                            curRange = [];
                        }
                    }
                    oldLine += lines.length;
                    newLine += lines.length;
                }
            }

            return ret.join('\n') + '\n';
        },

        applyPatch: function (oldStr, uniDiff) {
            var diffstr = uniDiff.split('\n');
            var diff = [];
            var remEOFNL = false,
                addEOFNL = false;

            for (var i = (diffstr[0][0] === 'I' ? 4 : 0); i < diffstr.length; i++) {
                if (diffstr[i][0] === '@') {
                    var meh = diffstr[i].split(/@@ -(\d+),(\d+) \+(\d+),(\d+) @@/);
                    diff.unshift({
                        start: meh[3],
                        oldlength: meh[2],
                        oldlines: [],
                        newlength: meh[4],
                        newlines: []
                    });
                } else if (diffstr[i][0] === '+') {
                    diff[0].newlines.push(diffstr[i].substr(1));
                } else if (diffstr[i][0] === '-') {
                    diff[0].oldlines.push(diffstr[i].substr(1));
                } else if (diffstr[i][0] === ' ') {
                    diff[0].newlines.push(diffstr[i].substr(1));
                    diff[0].oldlines.push(diffstr[i].substr(1));
                } else if (diffstr[i][0] === '\\') {
                    if (diffstr[i - 1][0] === '+') {
                        remEOFNL = true;
                    } else if (diffstr[i - 1][0] === '-') {
                        addEOFNL = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            var str = oldStr.split('\n');
            for (var i = diff.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                var d = diff[i];
                for (var j = 0; j < d.oldlength; j++) {
                    if (str[d.start - 1 + j] !== d.oldlines[j]) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                Array.prototype.splice.apply(str, [d.start - 1, +d.oldlength].concat(d.newlines));
            }

            if (remEOFNL) {
                while (!str[str.length - 1]) {
                    str.pop();
                }
            } else if (addEOFNL) {
                str.push('');
            }
            return str.join('\n');
        },

        convertChangesToXML: function (changes) {
            var ret = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < changes.length; i++) {
                var change = changes[i];
                if (change.added) {
                    ret.push("<ins class='diff'>");
                } else if (change.removed) {
                    ret.push("<del class='diff'>");
                }

                ret.push(escapeHTML(change.value));

                if (change.added) {
                    ret.push('</ins>');
                } else if (change.removed) {
                    ret.push('</del>');
                }
            }
            return ret.join('');
        },

        // See: http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/wiki/API
        convertChangesToDMP: function (changes) {
            var ret = [],
                change;
            for (var i = 0; i < changes.length; i++) {
                change = changes[i];
                ret.push([(change.added ? 1 : change.removed ? -1 : 0), change.value]);
            }
            return ret;
        }
    };
})();

if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
    module.exports = JsDiff;
}

var a = document.getElementById('a');
var b = document.getElementById('b');
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var diffType = "diffChars";

function check(){
    var oldStr = a.value;
    var newStr = b.value;
    var changes = JsDiff[diffType](oldStr, newStr);
    console.log(changes)
    result.innerHTML = JsDiff.convertChangesToXML(changes);
}

a.onkeyup = b.onkeyup = 
a.onpaste = a.onchange =
b.onpaste = b.onchange = check;
check();

var radio = document.getElementsByName('diff_type');
for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
 radio[i].onchange = function(e) {
  diffType = this.value;
  check();
 }
}
```

```css
del {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #b30000;
 background: #fadad7;
}
ins {
 background: #eaf2c2;
 color: #406619;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="diff_type" value="diffChars" checked> Chars</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="diff_type" value="diffWords"> Words</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="diff_type" value="diffLines"> Lines</label>
<label><input type='radio' name='diff_type' value='diffCss'> CSS</label>

<textarea id='a'>Foo bar is equal to bar foz.</textarea> <textarea id='b'>Foo bar is not equal to bar foo.</textarea>
<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: SO has a snippet thingy. Try it here see if it works. If it doesn't work, what's the error you get?

Comment: it works here too...

Comment: Then you most likely are doing something wrong on your project.

Comment: `it doesn't work` -- do you get any error messages?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null
    at script.js:413

Comment: pointing to line 413 b :        .onpaste = b.onchange = check;

Comment: There is no jQuery or React in the codepen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a javascript error, because the javascript is executing before the page is loaded.

move your script to the bottom of the page and it will work